# Compile error when using std::hash; does not name a template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors, stdhash

I am receiving the error

> "hashmap.hpp:63:14: error: ‘hash’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a
>   template type std::hash hash;"

I don't understand why i need to implement my own specialization when I'm passing in type T, which will probably be one of the types that works for the hash function.

hashmap.hpp

```
#ifndef __HASHMAP_HPP__
#define __HASHMAP_HPP__
#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 10
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

// A simple node struct for your separate chaining
// You may change this if you want
template <class K,class V>
struct KVNode
{
    K key;
    V value;
    KVNode<K,V>* next;
    KVNode(KVNode<K,V>* theNext = NULL) :
         next(theNext)
        {
        }
};

template <class K, class V>
class HashMap {
    public:
        // Default constructor: creates an empty hash map
        HashMap();
        // Constructor setting the default value for our map
        HashMap(V value);
        // Destructor: deallocates all memory associated
        // with the hash map
        ~HashMap();
        // size() returns the number of elements currently
        // stored in the hash map.
        unsigned int size() const;
        // set() inserts the given key value pair into the
        // hash map.  If the key is already in the map, then
        // the value for that key is overwritten.
        void set(const K& key, const V& value);
        // get() returns the value associated with the key.
        // If the key is not in the hash map, the default
        // value should be returned.
        V get(const K& key) const;
    private:
        // You are allowed to add any private variables you 
        // need to implement the functionality of a hash map
        // It is also okay to add addional public or private
        // methods you need, but you may not change the 
        // already existing method signatures.

        // You may find these private members useful, but you are
        // not required to use them.
        KVNode<K,V>** map;
        // To use this hash map with your own key type,
        // you may need to provide a specialization of std::hash.
        //std::hash<K> hash; #this was previous declaration but caused error
        std::hash<K> hash;
        // This is the default value to return if a key is not
        // in the hash map
        V default_value;
};


template <class K, class V>
HashMap<K,V>::HashMap() : default_value()
{
    KVNode<K,V>** map = new KVNode<K,V>*[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_CAPACITY; ++i)
        map[i] = new KVNode<K,V>();
}

template <class K, class V>
HashMap<K,V>::HashMap(V value)
{
    //TODO: Implement this method
}

template <class K, class V>
HashMap<K,V>::~HashMap()
{
    //TODO: Implement this method
}

template <class K, class V>
unsigned int HashMap<K,V>::size() const
{ 
    //TODO: Implement this method
}

template <class K, class V>
void HashMap<K,V>::set(const K& key, const V& value)
{
    //TODO: Implement this method
}

template <class K, class V>
V HashMap<K,V>::get(const K& key) const
{
    //TODO: Implement this method
}

#endif // __HASHMAP_HPP__
```

temp.cpp

```
 #include "hashmap.hpp"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <functional>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
  HashMap<string,int> hm = HashMap<string,int>();

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What's the compiler? Try compile it with option `-std=c++11`.

Comment: that did the trick! thank you. if you post it as a regular solution i can give you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) was introduced from C++11, you need C++11 supporting for using it.

If you work with GCC, you need to add the compilation option `-std=c++11`.